# Creating a loop to generate three separate plots read from three separate CSV files

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have three csv files that are essentially formatted the same. I generated a stacked bar plot for one of the files and I was wondering if there is a way to generate a loop to read the other two files and generate my other plots.

Here is my code:

```
DE_iterative_genotype_nr_12_sign_only <- read_delim("DE_iterative_genotype_nr_12_sign_only.csv", 
                                                    ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE) %>%
  melt()

TM_df_up <- DE_iterative_genotype_nr_12_sign_only %>% 
  filter(value>0) %>% #filtering for upregulated genes
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  count() %>% #summarises to give the number of DEGs per comparison
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(direction="up")

TM_df_down <- DE_iterative_genotype_nr_12_sign_only %>% 
  filter(value<0) %>% #filtering for downregulated genes
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(n=n*-1,direction="down") 

TM_df_plot <- rbind(TM_df_up, TM_df_down)

ggplot(TM_df_plot, (aes(x=variable, y=n, 
                        fill=direction, #up or down regulated
                        label=abs(n))))+ #label of number of DEGs as an absolute value
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(alpha=0.1))+
  geom_text(size = 6)+
  labs(y=NULL,x=NULL)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels= c("18 vs 20", #adding manual labels 
                             "20 vs 22",
                             "22 vs 24",
                             "24 vs DS"))+
  labs(
    x = "Days after pollentation",
    title = "TM_abi3-12 dog1-4cyp707a2"
  )+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))+ #changing the fill colours
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-2900, 16500, 550))+ #changing the scale breaks
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    text = element_text(size=24),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.35, hjust = 3),
    legend.position = "none"
  )

ggsave("triple mutant significant.png", width=10, height=27, dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a character vector `myfiles` of paths to files and one `myplots` with the path to the plots you want to save, you can loop through that:

```
myfiles <- c('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv')
myplots <- c('plot1.png', 'plot2.png', 'plot3.png')
for(i in 1:length(myfiles)) {   
  data <- read_delim(myfiles[i], 
                     ";", 
                     escape_double = FALSE, 
                     trim_ws = TRUE) %>% melt()

  TM_df_up <- data %>% 
    filter(value>0) %>% #filtering for upregulated genes
    group_by(variable) %>% 
    count() %>% #summarises to give the number of DEGs per comparison
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    mutate(direction="up")

  TM_df_down <- data %>% 
    filter(value<0) %>% #filtering for downregulated genes
    group_by(variable) %>% 
    count() %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    mutate(n=n*-1,direction="down") 

  TM_df_plot <- rbind(TM_df_up, TM_df_down)

  ggplot(TM_df_plot, (aes(x=variable, y=n, 
                          fill=direction, #up or down regulated
                          label=abs(n))))+ #label of number of DEGs as an absolute value
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(alpha=0.1))+
    geom_text(size = 6)+
    labs(y=NULL,x=NULL)+
    scale_x_discrete(labels= c("18 vs 20", #adding manual labels 
                               "20 vs 22",
                               "22 vs 24",
                               "24 vs DS"))+
    labs(
      x = "Days after pollentation",
      title = "TM_abi3-12 dog1-4cyp707a2"
    )+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))+ #changing the fill colours
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-2900, 16500, 550))+ #changing the scale breaks
    theme_minimal()+
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
      text = element_text(size=24),
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.35, hjust = 3),
      legend.position = "none"
    )
  ggsave(myplots[i], width=10, height=27, dpi=300) 
}
```